Vuetify, v-data-table header how to sort only on arrow icon click and not on item name (replaced by a v-text-field)
I want my header item to be filtered by a text search so I have replaced my header item with a v-text-field. So the label is the placeholder.
The issue is that when I click on the v-text-field it sorts asc or desc. I would like the sorting to happen only when I click on the arrow.
Do you have an idea of how to do that?

<v-data-table id="table" dense v-show="!$data.skeletonLoad" :page.sync="paginationData.page"
        :pageCount="paginationData.pageCount" :headers="head" fixed-header :items="dispItems"
        @pagination="paginationEvent" @page-count="paginationData.pageCount = $event" :options.sync="$data.listOptions"
        :server-items-length="totalItems" :loading="loading" class="elevation-0 mt-1 pt-1" :height="height"
        hide-default-footer>

 <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:[`header.${header.value}`]>
    <v-text-field hide-details dense v-bind:key="header.value" v-model="$data[header.value]" id="custom-input"
          class="data-table-header-text pt-4" :label="header.text" placeholder="Recherche" />
</template>


I have tried to put theses property in my v-data-table component :
<v-data-table :sort-key="sortKey" :sort-desc="sortDesc" @click:header="toggleSort">

my icon :
 <v-icon @click="toggleSort(header)" small :key="header.text"> {{ sortDesc ? 'mdi-chevron-down' : 'mdi-chevron-up' }}</v-icon>

My method :
methods: { toggleSort(headers) {
console.log('header', headers);
if (this.sortKey === headers.value) {
    this.sortDesc = !this.sortDesc;
    console.log('Sort order toggled:', this.sortDesc ? 'descending' : 'ascending');
  } else {
    this.sortKey = headers.value;
    this.sortDesc = false;
    console.log('Sort key changed:', this.sortKey);
  }
},

But i'm missing something. The sort-desc property seems not be recognized or used buy vuetify.
